# how to use @part and @field in retrofit in same api call

Tags: android, retrofit

```
@Multipart
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/upload")
void uploadImage(@Field("title") String title, @Field("description") String description, @Part("file") TypedFile photoFile, Callback<ImageVotingResponse> responseCallback);
```

I have this api call but I am not able to use @Multipart and @FormUrlEncoded at same time. Its giving me error like "Only one encoding annotation is allowed". Any solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

Use annotation @Multipart and change @Field to @Query annotation.

From postman doc

> urlencoded
>
> This encoding is the same as the one used in URL parameters. You just
>   need to enter key/value pairs and Postman will encode the keys and
>   values properly. Note that you can not upload files through this
>   encoding mode. There might be some confusion between form-data and
>   urlencoded so make sure to check with your API first.

Answer (score 0):

Use one annotation `@Multipart` or `@FormUrlEncoded`.